# Ломается CSS анимация

Tags: css

Пытаюсь раскрасить bootstrap menu... Нашёл красивую анимацию, применяю и анимация начинает выезжать за экран. Если ставить абсолютное позиционирование, то нужно вручную выставлять высоту, а это убивает отзывчивость, а если выставлять по высоте и ширине родителя, то она выезжает за экран

```css
.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  opacity:.5;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right:-50%;
  left:-50%;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    
      <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="bg bg2"></div>
    <div class="bg bg3"></div>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в CSS:

```
.navbar {overflow:hidden;}
```

Но учтите, что при этом не будут работать выпадающие меню, если они у вас появятся в дальнейшем.

UPD: рабочий вариант, где все будет ок. Обратите внимание, что у `.navbar` убран класс `.bg-light`

```css
.animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  opacity:.5;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right:-50%;
  left:-50%;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
    <div class="animation">
      <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="bg bg2"></div>
    <div class="bg bg3"></div>
</div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: А как вернуть в работу выпадающее меню?

Comment: Завернуть анимированый фон в отдельный контейнер и поиграться с position. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте

```
nav {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: А как вернуть в работу выпадающее меню?

Comment: @Алексей а как вы по обычным ссылкам кликаете? Они же неактивными становятся...